# How do I execute / loop a function in python/discord.py?

Tags: python, loops, discord.py, countdown, audio-player

I am trying to make a loop command in discord.py but it will only play once and not loop how do I make it so that everytime the video ends it will restart and play again, currently it only plays once and then does nothing. I tried some other ways but the most it just did was make it play twice, I want it to play infinetly till the user uses the ?stop command.

This is my code:

```
global loopURL
loopURL = ""

@commands.command()
    async def loop(self, ctx, *, arg):
        global loopURL
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send("Join a voice channel dumb fuck")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        try:
            requests.get("" + str(arg))
        except:
            arg = " " + str(arg)
        else:
            arg = "" + str(arg)
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': "bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
                          'options': '-vn'}
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{arg}", download=False)
            if 'entries' in info:
                video = info['entries'][0]
            else:
                video = info
            url2 = video['formats'][0]['url']
            loopURL == url2
            print(video)
            video_url = video['url']
            print(video_url)
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            await ctx.send("Now playing: **" + str(arg) + "**")
            vc.play(source)
            def convert(seconds):
                seconds = seconds % (24 * 3600)
                hour = seconds // 3600
                seconds %= 3600
                minutes = seconds // 60
                seconds %= 60
                return "%d:%02d:%02d" % (hour, minutes, seconds)

            print(video['title'])
            track = video['title']
            artist = video['channel']
            duration = video['duration']
            thumbnail = video['thumbnail']
            durationConv = convert(duration)
            embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Now playing", description=":notes: {}".format(track), color=0x00ff00)
            embedVar.add_field(name="Artist", value=":microphone: {}".format(artist), inline=False)
            embedVar.add_field(name="Duration", value=f":hourglass_flowing_sand: `{durationConv}`", inline=False)
            embedVar.set_thumbnail(url=thumbnail)
            await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
            t = duration

            def countdown(durationInt):
                while durationInt:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    durationInt -= 1
                    print(durationInt)
                    if durationInt == 0:
                        t == 0
                print("TIMER REACHED 0")
                return t
            countdown(t)
            if countdown(t) == 0:
                sourceloop = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(loopURL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
                vc.play(sourceloop)
                countdown(t)
                print(loopURL)
```

Comment: Where here do you believe you are looping?

Comment: At the countdown function

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a [background task](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html). There are some examples on the included page.